# Mongoose model stuck in an infinite loop - Node

Tags: node.js, mongoose, terminal

I'm setting up a basic schema for my mongo db, and when representing the schema as a variable, I get stuck in an infinite loop that logs *const mongoose = require('mongoose')* when using .load in node.

When I use the schema as an argument to the mongoose.model() function, the file is able to load perfectly fine in node.

This is what is creating the infinite loop -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false)
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');

let movie = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    score: Number,
    year: Number
});

const Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movie);
```

This is what is working perfectly fine -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false)
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');

const Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', { title: String, score: Number, year: Number });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to define schema

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose")

const movie = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  score: {
    type: Number,
  },
  year: {
    type: Number,
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Movie", movie)
```